# How to obtain nanosecond resolution relative time across cores in Mac OS X

Tags: c, multithreading, macos

I'm currently working on a project at work where I need to be able to measure relative elapsed time across cores & threads in the nanosecond resolution range. Googling around I was able to find the following code snippet:

```
kern_return_t ret;
clock_serv_t aClock;
mach_timespec_t aTime;

ret = host_get_clock_service(mach_host_self(), REALTIME_CLOCK,
                             &aClock);
if (ret != KERN_SUCCESS) {
    fprintf(stderr, "host_get_clock_service() failed: %s\n",
            mach_error_string(ret));
    abort();
}
ret = clock_get_time(aClock, &aTime);
if (ret != KERN_SUCCESS) {
    fprintf(stderr, "clock_get_time() failed: %s\n",
            mach_error_string(ret));
    abort();
}
```

Playing around with this this function clock_get_time does in fact return a struct which contains the number of seconds and nanoseconds that have elapsed since the CPU powered on. However, I'm unsure whether or not the value return by this function is safe to use across cores and threads.

I'm unable to find much documentation on this other than some man pages for the mach call. Has anybody tried this? If so could you point me in the way of documentation for this? I need to know definitively that the counter would be consistent across cores and threads.

I understand that this question is hardware and operating system specific. I am currently running Mac OS X 10.9 on an Intel Core i7 2.5 ghz processor.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The ***[Conversation here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/332570)*** is not Mac specific, but will at least provide a 'loosely' defined set of steps, or _concept_ of what _kind_ of steps are likely required to coordinate between cores.